# Seperate html files by tag name with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a large dataset of HTML files represented as text files (without the .html extension).
Each one of them contains several documents.
Each Doc in every file starts with `<DOC>` and ends with `</DOC>`

My goal is to separate every file to several files, that each one will contain one document, and save it separately.

I have tried to use BeautifulSoup but didn't figure it out.
Example of one file:

```html
<DOC>
<DOCNO> FBIS3-1 </DOCNO>
<HT>  "cr00000011094001" </HT>


<HEADER>
<H2>   March Reports </H2>
<DATE1>  1 March 1994 </DATE1>
Article Type:FBIS 
Document Type:FOREIGN MEDIA NOTE--FB PN 94-028 
<H3> <TI>      FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF MACEDONIA: OPINION POLLS ON </TI></H3>

</HEADER>


<TEXT>
POLITICIANS,  PARTY PREFERENCES 

</TEXT>

</DOC>




<DOC>
<DOCNO> FBIS3-1 </DOCNO>
<HT>  "cr00000011094001" </HT>


<HEADER>
<H2>   March Reports </H2>
<DATE1>  1 March 1994 </DATE1>
Article Type:FBIS 
Document Type:FOREIGN MEDIA NOTE--FB PN 94-028 
<H3> <TI>      FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF MACEDONIA: OPINION POLLS ON </TI></H3>

</HEADER>


<TEXT>
POLITICIANS,  PARTY PREFERENCES 

ELAG/25 February/POLCHF/EED/DEW 28/2023Z FEB 

</TEXT>

</DOC>
```

The code I have tried:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class ReadFile:

    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.file_counter = 0
        self.root_dir = path
        self.paths = None

    def create_file_set(self):
        file_set = set()
        for dir_, _, files in os.walk(self.root_dir):
            for file_name in files:
                rel_dir = os.path.relpath(dir_, self.root_dir)
                rel_file = os.path.join(rel_dir, file_name)
                rel_file = os.path.join(self.root_dir, rel_file)
                file_set.add(rel_file)
                self.file_counter += 1
        self.paths = file_set

    def doc_separation(self):
        for path in self.paths:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path), 'html')
            for tag in soup.find_all('DOC'):
                print(tag.name, tag.text)
```

Comment: please add code you have tried

Comment: And an example files as well plz

Comment: I don't understand your goal. What is your problem ??

Answer (score 0):

#### Change 'DOC' to 'doc'

```
def doc_separation(self):
for path in self.paths:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(path), 'lxml')
    for tag in soup.find_all('doc'):
        print(tag.name, tag.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I figure it out:

this is the class ReadFile:

```
def __init__(self, path: str):
    self.file_counter = 0
    self.root_dir = path
    self.paths = None

def create_file_set(self):
    file_set = set()
    for dir_, _, files in os.walk(self.root_dir):
        for file_name in files:
            rel_dir = os.path.relpath(dir_, self.root_dir)
            rel_file = os.path.join(rel_dir, file_name)
            rel_file = os.path.join(self.root_dir, rel_file)
            file_set.add(rel_file)
            self.file_counter += 1
    self.paths = file_set

def doc_separation(self):
    for path in self.paths:
        spltd_path = path.split('/')
        comb_path = '/' + "/".join([x for x in spltd_path[1:len(spltd_path)-1]])
        print(comb_path)
        with codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
            docs = soup.find_all('doc')
            for doc_ind, doc in enumerate(docs, 1):
                new_file_name = comb_path + '/' + "doc{}".format(doc_ind)
                file = open(new_file_name, "w")
                file.write(str(doc))
                file.close()
```